# Admin controller not working for subfolder in spring JSP page

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am not able give common Admin controller to subfolder in spring is there any solution

It's Taking admin controller as JSP page name.
Example
Return JSP/loginAController;
JSP is subfolder name,
login is page name ,
AController is admin controller